# Не происходит авторизация

Tags: php

Ребят, нужна помощь - не работает режим сессии, при выходе и в принципе при неавторизации таблица с данными отображается, а должна только для тех кто зарегистрирован..

**процесс авторизации (login.php)**

```
<?php 

include 'db.php';

$login = filter_var(trim($_POST['login']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$password = filter_var(trim($_POST['password']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE 'login'= '$login'"); 
$check = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

 if (password_verify($password, $hash)) 
  {

    $_SESSION['logged_user'] = $login;
    header('Location: lk.php');

  } else 
    {
        exit ("Извините, введённый вами логин или пароль неверный.");
      }
```

**Страница, после авторизации (lk.php):**

```
<?php
  include ("db.php");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title> Тестовое задание - личный кабинет </title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    
    if(isset($_SESSION['logged_user']))
    { 
?>
  <p> Привет, <?php echo $_SESSION['login'] ?> | <a href="exit.php">Выйти</a> </p> 
  <table border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="5">
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>Login</th>
    <th>password</th>
  </tr>
    <?php
        $r1 = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users");
        while ( ($us = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($r1)) )
          {
            echo '<tr><td>' . $us['id'] . '</td><td>' . $us['login'] . '</td><td>' . $us['password'] . '</td><tr>';
          }
    ?>
  </table>
    <?php
    }
      else
        {
          echo "Зарегистрируйтесь, чтобы просматривать эту страницу";
        }
     ?>
     
</body>
</html>
```

**Выход из сессии оформлен через**

```
unset($_SESSION['logged_user']);
```

**Функцию начала сессии залил в db.php:**

```
<?php

$connection = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'test_beeline');

if ($connection == false)
{
  echo 'Ошибка подключения';
  echo mysqli_connect_error();
  exit();
}

session_start();
```

Comment: f(isset($_SESSION['logged_user'])) - проверьте на этом этапе, что лежит по ключу logged_user. Возможно вы все-таки не разлогинились.

Comment: Да, спасибо проблема определенно в этом, только почему сессия не убивается.. Вопрос..

Answer (score 1):

Ты сравниваешь пароль с $_POST с хэшем, который создал от него же, далее условие будет исполняться всегда.

```
$password = filter_var(trim($_POST['password']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Не совсем понял, я отфильтровал пароль, полученный с поста и вернул его в переменную, а затем уже отфильтрованный пароль сунул в хэш, в чем проблема?
Фильтр FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING возвращает отфильтрованное значение в переменную.

Comment: Затем в условии ты его же и проверяешь if (password_verify($password, $hash)) , а нужно проверять со значением взятым из бд

Comment: @Evgeny, if (password_verify($password, $сheck["password"]))

Comment: Спасибо большое))